# Mongodb colletion generate a query like reply and sub reply

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am currently working on a comment and reply section, but I am facing a challenge with the reply complexity , as it involves multiple levels of replies. I am attempting to create a collection below and formulate an aggregate statement, but so far, I have not been successful

```
[
  {
    "_id": "reply_id_1",
    "text": "Reply to the comment",
    "author": "Jane Doe",
    "path": "C/comment_id"
  },
  {
    "_id": "reply_id_2",
    "text": "Another reply",
    "author": "Bob",
    "path": "R/reply_id_1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "reply_id_3",
    "text": "Another reply",
    "author": "Bob",
    "path": "R/reply_id_2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "reply_id_4",
    "text": "Another reply",
    "author": "Bob",
    "path": "R/reply_id_3"
  }
]
```

I am looking below response, because avoiding multiple looping in client side

```
  {
    "_id": "R/reply_id_1",
    "text": "Reply to the comment",
    "author": "Jane Doe",
    "path": "C/comment_id",
    "replies": [
      {
        "_id": "R/reply_id_2",
        "text": "Another reply",
        "author": "Bob",
        "path": "R/reply_id_1",
        "replies": [
          {
            "_id": "R/reply_id_3",
            "text": "Another reply",
            "author": "Bob",
            "path": "R/reply_id_2",
            "replies": [
              {
                "_id": "R/reply_id_4",
                "text": "Another reply",
                "author": "Bob",
                "path": "R/reply_id_3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Please suggest a more suitable data structure for this, excluding collation and sub-collection. I am seeking a separate collection for each reply to facilitate future analytics.

Comment: There is no native MongoDB aggregation API for generating a structure with dynamic nesting depth. You have to resort to application-level processing.